# Laravel5 how to still return the actual $latest article after the current latest gets deleted?

Tags: php, laravel-5, return-value

I've just built a blog based on "Laravel 5 fundamentals", then I added the delete option for the articles myself. In my navbar there is an option called "Latest article", which consists of:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>{!! link_to_action('ArticlesController@show', 'Latest Article', [$latest->id])  !!}</li>
</ul>
```

where the $latest comes from:

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('partials.nav', function($view){

        $view->with('latest', \App\Article::latest()->first());

    });
}
```

But after I go to the latest article and delete it, then I click on the "Latest Article" again, it gives me the error "ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\Article]" (I think it doesn't find the same article again which has just been deleted). 
How could I manage to always return the latest article? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is normal behavior. The link of Latest Article was rendered on the page before you delete it, so it's obvious that the link will work no more.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, but how could I render the actual latest article at every refresh-reload?

Comment: You could write a custom route like /pages/always-the-latest which then queries the latest and returns the view with it.

Comment: That's one good solution, which I'm gonna apply for the time being. But what about that case, if I'd like to display the name of the article in the navigation, because in this case it would still show the deleted one's name. How to always retrieve the actual $latest article into the partials.nav view? :)

Comment: you'll need to refresh it - depends on what you use as frontend framework (jquery+ ajax for exmaple) - on delete => re read the latest article and refresh what is shown

Comment: That's a bit too advanced for me yet, at least it seems to be from such a short description.